# Caracteres estranho em assunto de mensagem, utilizando wp_mail

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Boa noite, gostaria que alguém me ajudasse nessa, desenvolvi plugin wordpress, envia e-mails perfeitamente, porém quando assunto contém acentuação, o assunto é exibido de forma estranha, vejam...

O assunto chega dessa forma... **=??Q?=C3=89_somente_um_teste.?=**

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que seja??
Esse é o código que estou usando para enviar e-mails...

```
/// to
$to = $args['send_to'];
/// message
$that_message = self::preg_parse($msg['mp_message'], $args);
/// subject
$subject = "É somente um teste.";
/// headers
$headers = array('Content-type: text/html;');

wp_mail($to, $subject, $that_message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode passar o charset, dizendo qual o tipo de codificação do seu HTML, já que o habilitou pelo seu headers desta maneira:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder @Michel Simões funcionou perfeitamente...